# How to execute multiple JUnit test suite at a time..!

Tags: maven, junit

I have written a multiple JUnit test suite for running multiple test cases.(multiple JUnit test like AllTest1.java/AllTest2.java is requirement of my web project)

Now, I want to run my multiple test suite classes (AllTest1.java/AllTest2.java) at a time means on same build time.. for this I used maven-surefire-plugin but not able to execute both same time I have used many logic to execute but not successed:(..Is there any way to execute both test-suite parallely .
Any help will be appreciated.

This is my current maven-surefire-plugin configuration:

```
 <plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.8.1/version>
 <configuration>
 <includes>
 <include>**/AllTests1.java</include>
 </includes>
 <excludes>
 <exclude>**/AllTests2.java</exclude>
 </excludes>
 </configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
  <id>integration-test</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>integration-test</goal>
  </goals>
</execution>
<execution>
  <id>verify</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>verify</goal>
  </goals>
</execution>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks indeed like integration tests and unit tests or a combination of both. For such purposes i would suggest to use the [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html) to run the integration tests which should follow the [naming schema](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes):

```
<includes>
 <include>**/IT*.java</include>
 <include>**/*IT.java</include>
 <include>**/*ITCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

Furthermore the usual unit tests will be executed by the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) which should follow the following [naming schema](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes):

```
<includes>
 <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
 <include>**/*Test.java</include>
 <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

Furthermore you should avoid using test suites, cause based on the naming schema it can be distinguished if it's a unit- or integration tests.

After you changed to the above schema you can run the unit tests by

```
mvn test
```

running the integration tests by using:

```
mvn verify
```